# Is there any difference between "in matters of," "regarding," "when it comes to" and others?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

When I read press articles, these phrases come up again and again and I am under the impression they all mean the same thing (= about) but is there any difference between these phrases? Here is the same sentence with the different phrases:
1. The British government is no better than fast food companies **as far as** social legislation **is concerned**.
2. The British government is no better than fast food companies **regarding** social legislation.
3. The British government is no better than fast food companies **concerning** social legislation.
4. The British government is no better than fast food companies **in matters of** social legislation.
5. The British government is no better than fast food companies **in terms of** social legislation.
6. The British government is no better than fast food  companies **when it comes to** social legislation.
The last one sounds better but is it because it is more informal (or so I have been told)?
Thanks.

Comment: It's a somewhat confusing assertion, however the final element is phrased. Fast food companies must ***obey*** laws, but the British government ***makes*** laws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say these all have the same meaning, but vary *in terms of* formality :)

- "as far as x is concerned": very common and works both formally and informally; you can also use this a bit differently to express an opinion ("As far as I'm concerned, he's a real jerk!")
- "regarding": formal, though you might say this on the phone if you're trying to be polite
- "concerning": formal and rarely heard in speech
- "in matters of": formal and rarely heard in speech
- "in terms of": very common and only slightly formal
- "when it comes to": very common and informal

There's one more I'll point out: "as far as x goes" is also very common and informal.